# Run a script on files sent to a CUPS print queue?

Tags: macos, cups

I am trying to configure a Mac OS X print queue so that a script can do some processing on each file printed before forwarding it on to another CUPS printer (on the same host).

I have been reading up on CUPS and have found an article describing how to use lpadmin to configure a queue with a "System V style interface script", but the caveat is that such a queue is seen as a "Generic Printer". I presume that means the user looses all ability to choose paper trays, etc. when submitting a job from the Print dialog. Is that correct?

[That makes this approach undesirable for my purposes, because the final destination is a POS receipt printer with non-standard paper sizes and print job options for cutting the paper roll, opening the cash drawer, etc.]

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal, which is simply to run a script on each receipt printed through a particular CUPS print queue?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to configure a cups filter, which I believe can be created for just about any printer.  It basically works as an input/output filter - where you modify the job in flight.

anyway, here is a link I found that explains an approach to do so (although it is for a slightly different use case).  hope it helps.

[Programming a Filter/Backend to 'Print to PDF' with CUPS from any Mac OS X application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192396/programming-a-filter-backend-to-print-to-pdf-with-cups-from-any-mac-os-x-appli)

be well.